# Convert string of a hex value to integer

Tags: c, string, hex

How can I convert the string `0x26B70A40` to an `int` in c?

```
const char s[13] = "0x26B70A40";
int x = someFunction(s);
printf("%d\n", x);
```

That should print `649529920`.

Comment: look into strtoul(3)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`strtol()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) function from `stdlib.h`.

Excerpt from the man page,

> The string may begin with an arbitrary amount of white space (as determined by isspace(3)) followed by a single optional `'+'` or `'-'` sign. **If base is zero or 16, the string may then include a `"0x"` prefix, and the number will be read in base 16;** [....]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function strtol(char *str, char *end, int base).

```
int x = strtol(s,NULL,16);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `strtol()` function:

```
const char *hexstring = "0x26B70A40";
int x = (int)strtol(hexstring, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Actually I deleted my comment based on the quoted man page text in Sourav Ghosh's answer.  The documentation I was looking at did not suggest that 16 was also valid.  However I think zero is better - you then have the option of decimal or octal processing without changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 const char s[13] = "0x26B70A40";
 char **ptr;
 long val;
 val = strtol(s, ptr, 16);
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that `strtol()` has been suggested in three answers already, this code is also incorrect. `str` does not exist, and `ptr` is unitialised.  `prt` should be of type `char*` and then '&prt` passed if needed, but in this case serves no purpose, so NULL could be passed.